# Using PHP in Magento custom variables

Tags: php, email, magento, var, transactional

I cannot find a real answer to this. I am setting up a transactional email for a custom shipment notification. Basically I just want to take the date and add 8 days to it.

The PHP for that is ridiculously simple:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("+8 days");
return date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
```

So it seems like serious overkill to go through the problem of adding all the XML and functions to magento to do that. Is there a way to put that PHP into a custom variable (Or even the transactional template itself - I am not picky)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create phtml file and include it in mail template.

Put below code in mail template.

> {{block type='core/template' area='frontend'
>   template='customfiles/date.phtml'}}

Then create date.phtml file and place your php code in date.phtml

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customfiles/date.phtml

Comment: You know, here's the weird thing - I followed the steps in this page (http://www.srikanth.me/magento-customizing-email-templates/) exactly. I just copy and pastes the code from the page to the files specified and then tried to drop the call to it into my email template. And it doesn't work... I am not entirely sure what is going on but is there any chance that Magento 1.9.0.1 might have some sort of known bug (That I can't find listed anywhere) where that stuff doesn't work?

Comment: if you are trying my code then dont put **return** before **date_format($date,"Y-m-d");** just put **echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");**

Comment: Yes - I tried that. It actually get's worse - right now everything but the new date shows up. But putting the code in the phtml and placing it in that directory actually causes me to see nothing at all when I try to preview it.